# Awk field printing within the ternary operator

Tags: bash, awk

If you're familiar with [DISA STIGs](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/Pages/index.aspx), the test for [RHEL-06-000518](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_6/2013-02-05/finding/RHEL-06-000518) is

```
/bin/rpm -Va 2>/dev/null \
  | /bin/grep '^.M'
```

What I want to do is pull just the file name out of that test, and make pretty output with the package name and the offending file. However, my awk isn't doing it. Here's what I'm trying:

```
/bin/rpm -Va 2>/dev/null \
  | grep '^.M' \
  | awk '{print ($2 ~ /./ ? $3 : $2)}'
```

which, in theory, tells awk to print field 3 if field 2 is one of the single-character file types (%config, %documentation, etc., see the [rpm man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm))

However, what I get is the file name if-and-only-if ($2 ~ /./). Otherwise, I just get a blank line, even if I substitute $0 for that final $2.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your  test `$2 ~ /./` is always true, except when `$2` is the empty string, ie when there is 0 or 1 field in the line. You should try `$2 ~ /^.$/`.

You can also combine the grep and awk into one:

```
 awk '/^.M/ {print ($2 ~ /^.$/ ? $3 : $2)}'
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you! Regarding the modified awk, the next STIG in the series, 000519, does something similar. However, I don't want to deviate *too* much from the test-as-given, so I don't confuse any code review folks, auditors, etc...

Comment: ok. don't forget the anchor `^` in the grep: `grep '^.M'`, to match only the 2nd char in the line.

Comment: Whoops! The does does have the '^.M'. I just neglected to type that character when I typed the question. :) Edited and fixed.

Comment: good answer. An alternative (perhaps slightly faster too) to `$2 ~ /^.$/` is `length($2) == 1`